# mapreduce cassandra giving classcast Exception

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, cassandra

This is my code:

```
    public class CopyOfCassandraMapRed extends Configured implements Tool {
        private static final String KEYSPACE = "keyspace1";
        private static final String COLUMN_FAMILY = "users";
        private static final String CONF_COLUMN_NAME = "columnName";
        private static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
        private String OUTPUT_COLUMN_FAMILY = "OPt_CF";

        public static class CassandraMap extends
                Mapper<String, SortedMap<byte[], IColumn>, Text, LongWritable> {
            private final static LongWritable one = new LongWritable(1);
            private Text word = new Text();
            private String columnName;

            protected void map(String key, SortedMap<byte[], IColumn> columns,
                    Context context) throws java.io.IOException,
                    InterruptedException {
                IColumn column = columns.get(columnName.getBytes());
                if (column == null) {
                    return;
                }

                word.set(new String(columnName));
                context.write(word, one);
            }

            protected void setup(Context context) throws java.io.IOException,
                    InterruptedException {
                this.columnName = context.getConfiguration().get(CONF_COLUMN_NAME);
            }
        }

        public static class CassandraReduce extends
                Reducer<Text, LongWritable, Text, LongWritable> {
            private LongWritable result = new LongWritable();

            protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<LongWritable> values,
                    Context context) throws java.io.IOException,
                    InterruptedException {
                long sum = 0;
                for (LongWritable val : values) {
                    sum += val.get();
                }

                result.set(sum);
                context.write(key, result);
            }
        }

        public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
            String outputPath = args[1];
            Configuration conf = getConf();

            conf.set(CONF_COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_NAME);
            Job job = new Job(conf, "CassandraMapRed");
            job.setJarByClass(CopyOfCassandraMapRed.class);

            job.setMapperClass(CassandraMap.class);
            job.setCombinerClass(CassandraReduce.class);
            job.setReducerClass(CassandraReduce.class);

            job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
            job.setOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);

            job.setInputFormatClass(ColumnFamilyInputFormat.class);
            FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(outputPath));

            ConfigHelper.setInputRpcPort(job.getConfiguration(), "9160");
            ConfigHelper
                    .setInputInitialAddress(job.getConfiguration(), "localhost");
            ConfigHelper.setInputPartitioner(job.getConfiguration(),
                    "org.apache.cassandra.dht.RandomPartitioner");

            ConfigHelper.setInputColumnFamily(job.getConfiguration(), KEYSPACE,
                    COLUMN_FAMILY);
            ConfigHelper.setOutputColumnFamily(job.getConfiguration(), KEYSPACE,
                    OUTPUT_COLUMN_FAMILY);

            SlicePredicate predicate = new SlicePredicate().setColumn_names(Arrays
                    .asList(ByteBufferUtil.bytes(COLUMN_NAME) /*
                                                             * ByteBufferUtil.bytes(
                                                             * "text")
                                                             */));

            ConfigHelper.setInputSlicePredicate(job.getConfiguration(), predicate);

            System.out.println("running job now..");

            boolean success = job.waitForCompletion(true);

            return success ? 0 : 1;

        }
    }
```

---

On compiling it with the main class

```
    package com.manual;


    public class Hassandra {

        private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(Hassandra.class);

        private static final String CASSANDRA = "cassandra";

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Hassandra h = new Hassandra();
            // args[1] = "/home/user/Desktop/hadoopCass.op";
            System.exit(h.run(args));

        }

        public int run(String[] args) {
            StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
            stopWatch.start();

            int status = -1;

            try {
                // status = ToolRunner.run((Tool) new MapReducerDemo(), args);
                status = ToolRunner.run(new CopyOfCassandraMapRed(), args);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            stopWatch.stop();
            log.info("response time: " + stopWatch.getTime());
            return status;
        }

    }
```

---

I'm Getting an Exception here-

```
    java.lang.Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.nio.HeapByteBuffer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:354)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.nio.HeapByteBuffer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
        at com.manual.CopyOfCassandraMapRed$CassandraMap.map(CopyOfCassandraMapRed.java:1)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:223)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    14/01/28 14:54:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 99% reduce 0%
    14/01/28 14:54:28 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_local918272987_0001
    14/01/28 14:54:28 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 15
    14/01/28 14:54:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:   File Input Format Counters 
    14/01/28 14:54:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Bytes Read=0
    14/01/28 14:54:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:   FileSystemCounters
    14/01/28 14:54:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_READ=142637420
    14/01/28 14:54:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN=22830572
    14/01/28 14:54:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Map-Reduce Framework
    14/01/28 14:54:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output materialized bytes=1536
    14/01/28 14:54:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine output records=0
    14/01/28 14:54:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input records=1
    14/01/28 14:54:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=0
    14/01/28 14:54:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Spilled Records=0
    14/01/28 14:54:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output bytes=0
    14/01/28 14:54:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total committed heap usage (bytes)=190955126784
    14/01/28 14:54:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:     CPU time spent (ms)=0
    14/01/28 14:54:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=0
    14/01/28 14:54:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SPLIT_RAW_BYTES=26532
    14/01/28 14:54:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output records=0
    14/01/28 14:54:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine input records=0
    14/01/28 14:54:28 INFO manual.Hassandra: response time: 26230
```

can anyone tell me how to handle this exception?

these are my entries in the column family

```
    [default@user] list users;
    Using default limit of 100
    Using default cell limit of 100
    -------------------
    RowKey: key1
    => (name=name, value=myName, timestamp=1390899337732000)

    1 Row Returned.
```

Answer (score 1):

Switch from

```
public static class CassandraMap extends
            Mapper<String, SortedMap<byte[], IColumn>, Text, LongWritable>
```

to

```
public static class CassandraMap extends
            Mapper<ByteBuffer, SortedMap<byte[], IColumn>, Text, LongWritable>
```

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.cassandra/cassandra-all/2.0.1/org/apache/cassandra/hadoop/ColumnFamilyInputFormat.java returns ByteBuffers, not Strings.

Comment: but still not working, so i give up and trying another example.

Comment: What exception is it this time?